# Two Way Value Changing with Create React App

Tags: node.js, database, reactjs, websocket, create-react-app

Title is a bit confusing, let me give you an example.
[image]

### **2 Devices running on Network.**

1. Mobile
2. Laptop

[image]
If I type "Hello" on my mobile, How can I see the same thing on my Laptop environment (dynamically).

**My Thinking:**

Creating a JSON file with just one value in it and update it *onChange* of TextField.

Comment: Do you want to sync the data in the app, or just for your own environment when developing? It might be worth looking into [Browsersync](https://www.browsersync.io/) if you mean the latter.

Comment: You basically need to implement some sort of database if you want this to work in a real environment. Firebase would be an easy starting point due to it's real-time sync.

Comment: @JeremyLee, I thought of the same, I can get the Firebase set up but is there an alternative to that? Let me see Tholle's suggestion.

Comment: [Socket.IO](https://socket.io) is a good option too to share data in real-time

Comment: Isn't there a way to get it without using any third party like socket.io or Firebase or any of those things?

Comment: No. You are syncing data across computers. Without a shared resource that they both have access to they can't be showing the same data. That's what databases are for.

Comment: @molamk, would you mind suggesting some good tutorials for Socket.io?

Comment: FYI - What I did with your help https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:6501606308096069632/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do such thing without implementing some sort of backend/database to maintain the communication between the two devices.

As the comments said, you can use [Socket.IO](https://socket.io/) for example, or you can use [GraphQL Subscriptions](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/subscriptions.html).

That are many ways to do that, but if you don't want to implementing something like that from the zero, you will need to use some third-party software.

Comment: Unfortunately I had to use Firebase, that isn't bad though. And got 2 more things to learn over the weekend. Socket and GraphQL. Thank you for the help.